# Can we upload the Windows Application in IIS in .net

Tags: .net, windows, web-applications

I have a Windows application developed in .net c#. I want to put it in IIS similar to web application. Is it possible?

My requirement is: just like web application, I want to get the URL for this Windows application and use the link to remotely access the Windows application.

Comment: Me too have the same doubt. Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx).  Essentially, it allows for a simple installation from a website.  This is the simplest way to deploy what sounds like a very non-web app to your users.

Whether you can create a website to provide equivalent functionality really depends on the nature of your app.  Can you describe what your app does, or how it works?  That will help get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

IIS is mainly good for hosting HTTP-based applications, such as web sites, or web service applications.  If you are using WCF and IIS 7, you can actually host other types of services in IIS using Windows Activation Service (WAS).

What kind of application do you want to host in IIS?  One option would be to use WCF to host HTTP endpoints in a Windows service.  (See [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) class).  Running HTTP services outside of IIS might also require some additional permission/accessibility settings, (e.g. using the [HttpCfg](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787508%28WS.10%29.aspx) command).

Comment: Am not using any services like WCF,WPF,.. My Application is a simple windows application which performs some operation based on the input file of respective systems(may have .net frame work or maynot). So only, I thought to run the application in different systems thro URL similar to web application.

If it is not possible, please let me know how can I run this windows application in other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can share your folder which contains your standalone application.
If you use windows, RIght
Right click folder> Click Sharing > Then select SHare...

and follow instructions.
This will share it on the network, allowing those with privelages to access it.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot deploy a stand alone application on iis. However there is a way around to achieve this. pack your application in an msi, create a batch file that execute the msi silently and execute the exe. create a web app that downloads the batch and msi on clients computer and the execute the batch from the wb app. the bath will do the rest